# SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() vs EntityManager.createEntityManager()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, junit

So I had been working with Hibernate `SessionFactory` and its `getCurrentSession` method for inside a transaction for a while now.

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
```

and having it interact with other DAO classes within the same test. Switching to JPA though, can I inject a container managed `EntityManagerFactory` and then replacing the above with

```
EntityManager entityManager = myFactory.createEntityManager();
```

and then continue as session interface equivalents in `EntityManager` in current tests? Performing `entityManager.flush()` causes

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Comment: Just inject an `EntityManager` and call the methods on those. You don't need the `EntityManagerFactory` and create those yourself. Spring will take care of the transaction and proper injection.

Answer (score 1):

`.flush()` call must be part of a transaction. Either you create one or propagate from calling class using `@Transactional` annotation.

To create:

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

// Some DB operations

entityManager.flush();
entityManager.getTransaction().commit(); //commit() will do the flush anyway
```

If you want to to be part of calling class transaction, then include `@Transactional` annotation either at method or class level depending on design.

Comment: There is no need in `flush()` right before `commit()` :)

Comment: you are right. Already included that in // java comment. OP wanted to invoke the flush() so just included it.